# Solving modulus equations with multiple unknowns

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

I have the following equations:

$$8\equiv-(3a+7b)\mod11$$
and
$$9\equiv-(5a+4b)\mod11$$

How do I solve them?
I've tried to subtract one equation from the other, but I end up with the wrong answer.

It is supposed to be:
$a=2$ and $b=9$.

Comment: The method is the same as it always is for solving a system of linear equations.  If you show your calculation, perhaps we can spot where you went astray.

Comment: **Hint** $\bmod 11\!:\ 7\equiv -4\,$ so adding them **eliminates** $\,b,\,$ yielding $\,6\equiv 3a\ \ \ $

Comment: Worth emphasis: the (Gaussian) elimination method works the same $\!\bmod 11\,$  because the modulus is *prime* so we are working over a *field*, so $\,a\not\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, a^{-1}$ exists. This fails for nonprime moduli so we need to modify our methods in this case.

Answer (score 1):

By rearranging the first congruence equation $8 \equiv -3a -7b \pmod{11}$, we have $4b \equiv 8 + 3a \pmod{11}$. Since $\gcd(4, 11) = 1$, there is an inverse of $4$, which is $3$. We thus have
\begin{equation}
b \equiv 24 + 9a \equiv 2 - 2a \pmod{11}
\end{equation}
Plugging this into the other congruence equation $9 \equiv -5a - 4b \pmod{11}$. We have
\begin{equation}
9 \equiv -5a - 4(2 - 2a) \equiv 3a - 8 \pmod{11}
\end{equation}
which implies that $3a \equiv 17 \equiv 6 \pmod {11}$. Since $\gcd(3, 11) = 1$, we can divide by $3$. So, we have $a \equiv 2 \pmod{11}$. Using the same way, you can solve for $b$.